# Loading image in the Navigation Drawer header from custom URL

Tags: android, android-glide, android-design-library

I am not using any custom library to make the Navigation View. I am using the Navigation View from the Support Design Library. How would I be able to set the Header image to a custom image from the Internet using Glide or Fresco. Currently I have a static ImageView as the Drawer Header.

EDIT - The image needs to be of what size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set this in your `XML file` for `Navigation Header`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/nav_header_margin_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_margin_top"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And use `Glide` to set the image with a url in your `MainActivity`:

```
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //NavigationHeader
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        imageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            Glide
                .with(context)
                .load("your url")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.priceshoes)
                .error(R.drawable.priceshoes)
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, if I don't use these lines:

```
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    imageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I would get the error "Target must be not null", because on my setContentView() method I call activity_main and the ImageView of the profile picture is in the header layout in a separate xml.